# Does the WTO have a concept of “default” or standard tariffs?

Tags: trade, wto

Does the WTO have a concept of “default” or standard tariffs for when a state has not yet agreed schedules? Or does everything default to zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell: no, there's no such notion of default tariffs. So they don't default to zero... or to any figure. There's [one 2016 comment](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2016/jun/07/wto-chief-brexit-trade-talks-start-scratch-eu-referendum) by its director-general obliquely answering this:

> Britain is a member of the WTO and will continue to be a member of the WTO. But it will be [because of Brexit] a member with no country-specific commitments. We have had no other situation like that.

Normally tariffs (and quotas) are negotiated (with the existing members) when a country joins the WTO. (They can be [renegotiated thereafter](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32949/can-schedules-be-bilaterally-agreed-in-the-wto-forum/32952#32952).)

Also, in the mean time, Britain has submitted its modified schedules (in [July 2018](https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-eu-wto/britain-and-eu-formally-start-splitting-wto-membership-agreements-idUKKBN1KE2LJ)), and is currently awaiting a decision by the rest of the WTO. Which should also happen soonish; as I recall the other members have 90 days to respond, which have elapsed or nearly so.